# TypeORM - EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "anträge" was found

Tags: angular, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to update an entity in my Angular frontend, in my case an user (Benutzer), but I get the error **EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "anträge" was found.** in NestJS (TypeORM). The error comes, when I use the updateBenutzer Service/Controller. My code looks as follows:

*benutzer.entity.ts*

```
@Entity()
export class Benutzer {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int" })
    BenutzerID: number;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    Benutzername: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    Passwort: string;

    @Column({ default: false})
    istAdmin: boolean;

    @Column({ default: false})
    istVorgesetzter: boolean;

    @Column({ type: "int"})
    Vorgesetzter: number;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    Vorname: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    Nachname: string;

    @Column()
    Geburtsdatum: Date;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    Email: string;

    @Column()
    Eintrittsdatum: Date;

    @ManyToOne(() => Arbeitstage, arbeitstage => arbeitstage.allebenutzer)
    arbeitstage: Arbeitstage;

    @ManyToOne(() => Bundesland, bundesland => bundesland.alleBenutzer)
    bundesland: Bundesland;

    @OneToMany(() => Urlaubsantrag, urlaubsantrag => urlaubsantrag.benutzer)
    anträge: Urlaubsantrag[];
}
```

*urlaubsantrag.entity.ts*

```
@Entity()
export class Urlaubsantrag {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int" })
    AntragID: number;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50 })
    Urlaubsart: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    Status: string;
    @Column()
    von: Date;

    @Column()
    bis: Date;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    Grund: string;

    @Column()
    informiert: boolean;

    @ManyToOne(() => Benutzer, benutzer => benutzer.anträge, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    benutzer: Benutzer;
}
```

*benutzer.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class BenutzerService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Benutzer)
        private benutzerRepository: Repository<Benutzer>,
      ) {}
    
      getAllBenutzer(): Promise<Benutzer[]> {
        return this.benutzerRepository.find({ relations: ['bundesland', 'arbeitstage', 'anträge']});
      }
    
      findBenutzerByID(id: number): Promise<Benutzer> {
        return this.benutzerRepository.findOne(id, { relations: ['bundesland', 'arbeitstage', 'anträge']});
      }

      async findBenutzerByVorgesetzter(id: number): Promise<Benutzer[]> {
        return this.benutzerRepository.find({ where: {Vorgesetzter: id}});
      }

      getAllVorgesetzten(istVorgesetzter: boolean): Promise<Benutzer[]>{
        return this.benutzerRepository.find({ where: {istVorgesetzter: istVorgesetzter} });
      }

      async createBenutzer(benutzer: CreateBenutzer) {
        const nutzer = this.benutzerRepository.create(benutzer);
        await this.benutzerRepository.save(benutzer);
        return nutzer;
      }

      async updateBenutzer(id: number, createBenutzerDTO: CreateBenutzer) {
        return await this.benutzerRepository.update( id, createBenutzerDTO);
      }
    
      async deleteBenutzer(id: number): Promise<DeleteResult> {
        return await this.benutzerRepository.findOne(id).then((value) => {
          return this.benutzerRepository.delete(value);
        });
      }
}
```

*benutzer.controller.ts*

```
@Controller('benutzer')
export class BenutzerController {
    constructor(private readonly benutzerService: BenutzerService) {}

    @Post()
    async createBenutzer(@Body() createBenutzer: CreateBenutzer): Promise<Benutzer> {
    return this.benutzerService.createBenutzer(createBenutzer);
    }

    @Get()
    async getBenutzer(): Promise<Benutzer[]> {
        return this.benutzerService.getAllBenutzer();
    }

    @Get('/vorgesetzter')
    async getAllVorgesetzten(@Query('istVorgesetzter', new ParseBoolPipe()) istVorgesetzter: boolean): Promise<Benutzer[]>{
      return this.benutzerService.getAllVorgesetzten(istVorgesetzter);
    }

    @Get(':id')
    async getBenutzerByID(@Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id): Promise<Benutzer> {
        return this.benutzerService.findBenutzerByID(id);
    }

    @Get('/vorgesetzter/:id')
    async getBenutzerByVorgesetzter(@Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id): Promise<Benutzer[]> {
        return this.benutzerService.findBenutzerByVorgesetzter(id);
    }

    @Put(':id')
    updateBenutzer(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() createBenutzerDTO: CreateBenutzer) {
    return this.benutzerService.updateBenutzer(id, createBenutzerDTO);
    } 

    @Delete(':id')
    async remove(@Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id) {
    return this.benutzerService.deleteBenutzer(id);
  }
}
```

*create-benutzer.dto.ts*

```
    export class CreateBenutzer {
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    readonly Benutzername: string;

    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    //@Matches(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/, 
    //{message: 'das Passwort ist zu schwach'})
    readonly Passwort: string;
    readonly istAdmin: boolean;
    readonly istVorgesetzter: boolean;
    readonly Vorgesetzter: number;
    readonly Vorname: string;
    readonly Nachname: string;
    readonly Geburtsdatum: Date;
    readonly Email: string;
    readonly Eintrittsdatum: Date;
    readonly arbeitstage: Arbeitstage;
    readonly bundesland: Bundesland;
}
```

Comment: what is the createBenutzerDTO? You need to create an entity of type 'benutzer' using this dto and then perform the update operation. If that doesn't work, use the repository's save function instead

Comment: can you share the createBenutzerDTO code?

Comment: @Youba I added the dto file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you can use the Save method for updating the entity: 
*the reason is the save method executes a primitive operation without cascades and relations operations.*

```
 async updateBenutzer(id: number, createBenutzerDTO: CreateBenutzer) {

 let benutzerUpdate= await this.benutzerRepository.findOne({ BenutzerID:id});
 if(!benutzerUpdate) throw new NotFoundException({message:"Benutzer doesn't exist" });

    return this.benutzerRepository.save({...benutzerUpdate,...createBenutzerDTO});

  }
```